# Keyboard will not dismiss once DatePicker is selected

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using IQKeyBoardManager for my project build in Swift. I am having a problem in one specific View Controller. Once I keep going down my text fields and reach the date of birth text field, that is when I want the keyboard to be dismissed. I tried to add a function on once date picker value was changed to dismiss keyboard, however it did not work. I want the keyboard to be dismissed as soon as my datePicker is active. [image: datePicker]

```
     @objc func keyboardDoneClicked() {

    switch openedTextFieldTag {
    case 1:
            firstName.resignFirstResponder()
            lastName.becomeFirstResponder()
            routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    case 2:
            firstName.resignFirstResponder()
            lastName.resignFirstResponder()
            routing_number.becomeFirstResponder()
            account_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    case 3:
            firstName.resignFirstResponder()
            lastName.resignFirstResponder()
            routing_number.becomeFirstResponder()
            account_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    case 4:
            firstName.resignFirstResponder()
            lastName.resignFirstResponder()
            routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_number.becomeFirstResponder()
            account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    case 5:
            firstName.resignFirstResponder()
            lastName.resignFirstResponder()
            routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_number.resignFirstResponder()
            account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    default:
        break
    }
}


   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    openedTextFieldTag = 0
    if textField == self.date_of_birth {
        view.endEditing(true)
        self.datePicker.isHidden = false
        self.doneBtn.isHidden = false
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        date_of_birth.resignFirstResponder()
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
        routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.datePicker.isHidden = true
        self.doneBtn.isHidden = true
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == firstName {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.becomeFirstResponder()
        routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == lastName {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
        routing_number.becomeFirstResponder()
        account_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == routing_number {

        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
        routing_number.becomeFirstResponder()
        account_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == account_number {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
        routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_number.becomeFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == account_holder_name {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
        routing_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_number.resignFirstResponder()
        account_holder_name.resignFirstResponder()
        date_of_birth.resignFirstResponder()

        self.datePicker.isHidden = false
        self.doneBtn.isHidden = false
    }

    return true
}

  @objc func pickerEditingDidEnd(_ date: UIDatePicker ) {
    print(date)
    datePicker.isHidden = true
    self.doneBtn.isHidden = true

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    self.date_of_birth.text = formatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(datePicker.date, forKey: "dob")

}


    override func viewDidLoad(){
     datePicker.date = Date()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerEditingDidEnd), for: .editingDidEnd)
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.layer.borderColor = THEME_BLUE_COLOR.cgColor
    datePicker.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    datePicker.isHidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don’t know why you need to call `becomeFirstResponder()` and `resignFirstResponder()` for each TextField since they are automatically called when a touch is received on any TextField.

If you didn’t set each TextField’s delegate yet, you can try:

```
     override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

   firstName.delegate = self
   lastName.delegate = self
   routing_number.delegate = self
   account_holder_name.delegate = self



     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to write `becomeFirstResponder()` and `resignFirstResponder()` because `IQKeyBoardManager` will manage it. So remove all that for each text field and check that for date picker.

You can also try,

```
@objc func pickerEditingDidEnd(_ date: UIDatePicker ) {
    print(date)
    datePicker.isHidden = true
    self.doneBtn.isHidden = true

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    self.date_of_birth.text = formatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(datePicker.date, forKey: "dob")
    self.date_of_birth.resignFirstResponder()

}
```